# When to use "git add ." and when "git add -A"

Tags: git

Currently, when I want to make a commit and push the content to the remote Git repository, I use:

```
git add . //<--notice the dot here
git commit -m "some commit message"
git push
```

I have seen MANY people use `git add -A` instead. I read the difference between, `.` and `-A`, but I am not clear with it.

So are these two commands the same?

If not, when should one use `git add .` and when `git add -A`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`git add .` adds only the folder you're currently in, `git add -A` adds all the folders in the repository.

For example if your repo is called `foo` and you're in the folder `foo/bar`, and you changed the files `foo/file1.pl` and `foo/bar/file2.pl`, `git add .` would only stage `file2.pl` while `git add -A` would stage all files.

On the question of where to use which it depends on your working style: if you keep a clean repo at all times and you only change files which should be committed then you can use `git add -A`, otherwise it might be wiser to use `git add .` or even add the files manually. This being said, it's a good idea to *always* do a `git status` at the end to make sure you didn't commit something you shouldn't, cause once it's pushed it's hard to obliterate that data.

Comment: kudos on suggesting to add the files manually. It's just safer and you stay in control.

Answer (score 2):

```
git add -A
```

It adds all the files which has changes in all the folders of the repository.

```
git add .
```

It adds all the files which has changes in current folder.

Answer (score 1):

Since git version 2.0 the default is `git add -A`

From the release notes:
https://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/tree/Documentation/RelNotes/2.0.0.txt

> `git add <path>` is the same as `git add -A <path>` now, so that
>   `git add dir/` will notice paths you removed from the directory and
>   record the removal.  In older versions of Git, `git add <path>` used
>   to ignore removals.  You can say `git add --ignore-removal <path>` to
>   add only added or modified paths in , if you really want to.

Answer (score 0):

git add . adds the changed files from current directory and sub-directories. git add -A adds the changed files from all the directories.